# Network usage high even when idle

Tags: 14.04, networking, usb

Ubuntu 14.04.   PCI wifi card (Ralink 2561 chip)
Even with fresh boot with nothing running, system monitor indicates send rate of 40-50 KiB/s and receive of 20ish KiB/s.  Pulled the PCI card and inserted Alfa AWUSO36NHV (USB) and usage settled down.  Was using a cheap $3.00 USB wifi adapter and noticed this problem, so pulled that and inserted the PCI card and the problem went away for a few days, then began again. At present it's all good with the Alfa but I half expect the problem to crop up again in a few days as has already happened once.  Any ideas why this happens?

Did not run top.  Was not running any internet associated software and was not updating at the time.  Next time it happens, I'll run top and post a screen grab.

Comment: - Are you *sure* that the system is idle? I mean, can you run `top` to see what's running? Maybe an update in the background or something else can explain that activity...
- Also, which network interface are you talking about? ethX, lo, etc?B

Answer (score 0):

Your system is never idle. Install Wireshark (`wireshark-gtk`) and run it for a few seconds to see what the traffic is about. My guess is that you’ll see multicast broadcasts and other low-level chatter from other devices on your network.